# Grid stack Knockout JS widgets does not get removed when Browser is resized

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, gridstack

I am relatively new to [Gridstack](https://gridstackjs.com/) and [Knockout JS](https://knockoutjs.com/).

Trying to figure out for the past days why the widgets are not deleted properly whenever the browser is resized.

**Note:** this issue happens on all browsers.

**Scenario A:** "Without resizing Browser"

[Here's the initial display of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXP9T.jpg)

I am able to delete the widgets when the browser size is not changed.

**Scenario B:** "Browser is resized (Vertically)"

After adding widgets (or you can refresh the browser to display default again), I have resized the browser vertically.

[The widgets re-aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcLxL.jpg)

It's strange when I try to delete the widgets after it realigns it doesn't get removed.

Is this a known issue for Gridstack or Knockout?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Investigation Sample 1</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/tree/master/dist/gridstack.css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/tree/master/dist/gridstack.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/tree/master/dist/gridstack.jQueryUI.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .grid-stack {
      background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    }
    
    .grid-stack-item-content {
      color: #2c3e50;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #18bc9c;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <h1> Investigation Sample 1</h1>

    <div>
      <button data-bind="click: addNewWidget">Add new widget</button>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div data-bind="component: {name: 'dashboard-grid', params: $data}"></div>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    ko.components.register('dashboard-grid', {
      viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function(controller, componentInfo) {

          var ViewModel = function(controller, componentInfo) {

            var grid = null;

            this.widgets = controller.widgets;

            this.afterAddWidget = function(items) {

              if (grid == null) {
                grid = $(componentInfo.element).find('.grid-stack').gridstack({
                  auto: false
                }).data('gridstack');
              }

              var item = _.find(items, function(i) {
                return i.nodeType == 1
              });
              grid.addWidget(item);
              ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(item, function() {
                grid.removeWidget(item);
              });
            };
          };
          return new ViewModel(controller, componentInfo);
        }
      },
      template: [
        '<div class="grid-stack" data-bind="foreach: {data: widgets, afterRender: afterAddWidget}">',
        '   <div class="grid-stack-item" data-bind="attr: {\'data-gs-x\': $data.x, \'data-gs-y\': $data.y, \'data-gs-width\': $data.width, \'data-gs-height\': $data.height, \'data-gs-auto-position\': $data.auto_position}">',
        '       <div class="grid-stack-item-content"><button data-bind="click: $root.deleteWidget">Delete Button</button></div>',
        '   </div>',
        '</div> '
      ].join('')

    });

    $(function() {
      var Controller = function(widgets) {
        var self = this;

        this.widgets = ko.observableArray(widgets);

        this.addNewWidget = function() {
          this.widgets.push({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            //width: Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()),
            //height: Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()),
            width: 2,
            height: 3,
            auto_position: true
          });
          return false;
        };

        this.deleteWidget = function(item) {
          self.widgets.remove(item);
          return false;
        };
      };

      var widgets = [{
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: 2,
          height: 2
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          y: 0,
          width: 4,
          height: 2
        },
        {
          x: 6,
          y: 0,
          width: 2,
          height: 4
        },
        {
          x: 1,
          y: 2,
          width: 4,
          height: 2
        }
      ];

      var controller = new Controller(widgets);
      ko.applyBindings(controller);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```